# Can not find jnlp-api in java-8-openjdk

Tags: jnlp, java

Switched java platform from Oracle's jdk8 to openjdk and now cannot build maven project.

```
Could not find artifact javax.jnlp:jnlp-api:jar:8.0 at specified path /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/lib/javaws.jar
```

Switching back to oracle jdk8 allows the build to proceed.

Where can I find jnlp-api for openjdk 8? Is there a POM available?

Comment: Is JNLP part of openjdk?  I thought icedtea was meant to fix that gap. :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IcedTea